# What is the price of overweight luggage on Aer Lingus?

Tags: luggage, airlines

In the `Travel informations > Baggage information > Checked baggage` section of [the Aer Lingus website](http://www.aerlingus.com/travelinformation/baggageinformation/checkedbaggage/#checkedbaggagefeestable), it's written:

> Excess weight will be charged per kilo per flight for any passenger exceeding their personal checked baggage allowance at the airport on the day of travel.

How much does that cost per kilo?

Comment: Apparently, [it's 9 EUR/kg if booked in advance and EUR 15/kg at the airport](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/aer-lingus-gold-circle-club/1496968-additional-bag-fees.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aer Lingus](http://www.aerlingus.com/i18n/en/htmlPopups/fees.html) has a section on overweight fee, but it lists it as a flat fee. Perhaps there is some mistake on either page.

Excess baggage fees: Longhaul flights - all bags over 23kg-32kgs (50lbs-70lbs)

75 euros, or
65 British Pounds, or
100  US Dollars

Shorthaul flights - per kg over allowance (airport only)
15 euros, or
12 British Pounds,or
- US Dollars (Unexplained - possibly: invalid on short-haul flight)

Comment: The other page is about flights “within Europe”, so short-haul flights.